# Is there a way I can modify my page background color to show as random shades with svg?

Tags: svg

I have a black #000 page background on my web page.

Is there a way that I can change this with SVG to show a random effect of small #111 and #222 colored squares.  I was told I could do this with SVG but I don't have any idea where to start. Even a really simple example would be a great help.

I'm looking for a solution for IE9+ browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVGs can be used as background images they same way that a PNG or JPG can.  Create an SVG with any suitable editor - such as Inkscape - and include it the way you normally would.

```
background-image: url(../images/mybackground.svg);
```